# No step-definition method match found for: listen

Tags: karate

I am trying to understand how to handle async call in karate framework.
As a first step, I created a ActiveMQConsumer to listen to the msg from the queue.
I am getting "**no step-definition method match found for: listen 10000**" error.

Listed below is my feature file.

```
Feature: Test

Background:

* def QueueConsumer = Java.type('test.amqtest.ActiveMQConsumer')
* def queue = new QueueConsumer("AsyncTest")
* def handler = function(msg){ karate.signal(msg)}
* queue.listen(handler)

Scenario: TestScenario

* listen 10000
* print listenResult
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`listen` is only in 1.X - you must be on an old version.

Upgrade.